# IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class TeamEventPropertiesDetail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

When I try to invoke stateless session EJB's remote method by passing list of objects, I get this

```
"IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class TeamEventPropertiesDetail"
```

The interesting part is, when that list is empty the remote method gets invoked without any problem. If the list holds any object, it gives the following problem while invoking:

```
"IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class TeamEventPropertiesDetail"
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:9679)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:9694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1042)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:896)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:890)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:880)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:386)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:547)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:345)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1688)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1211)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:422)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:966)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1052)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:475)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1983)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2208)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1220)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:422)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:966)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1052)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:475)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:687)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(BCELStubBase.java:225)
    at com.commlinkinfotech.cbs.crm.ejb.session.stateless.__TeamActivitiesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.edit(com/commlinkinfotech/cbs/crm/ejb/session/stateless/__TeamActivitiesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at com.commlinkinfotech.cbs.crm.ejb.session.stateless._TeamActivitiesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.edit(com/commlinkinfotech/cbs/crm/ejb/session/stateless/_TeamActivitiesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at com.commlinkinfotech.cbs.crm.handler.TeamActivitiesHandler.editTeamActivities(TeamActivitiesHandler.java:103)
    at com.commlinkinfotech.cbs.crm.controller.TeamActivitiesController.editTeamActivities(TeamActivitiesController.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

**Code:**

```
public class TeamActivities
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamActivities", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_activities_id_nr")
    private List<TeamEventProperties> teamEventPropertiesList;

}

public class TeamEventProperties 
{
    //...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_activities_id_nr")
    private TeamActivities teamActivities;    
}
```

The exception occurs in the following line which persists the teamActivitiesDetail object with a list of teamEventPropertiesDetail.

```
TeamActivitiesHandler.editTeamActivities(teamActivitiesDetail);
```

I found the similar problem [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/441491/EJB-JEE/java/IOP-MARSHAL-load-class-Class) which is pretty old (2008) but I am facing the problem in 2014! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407148/could-not-load-class-persistentbag) is another one but I didn't solved it by this solution too.

Can anyone give any insight? I am stuck with this problem for more than 1 day.

Comment: Although I make a solution by changing my glassfish version, is there any solution for glassfish v2 ? Can anyone share any info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I've come up with is an interesting one which is not related to this code! I've solved the problem by changing the `glassfish` server version `from 2.1 to 3.1.2`.

Still I am confused why this feature not available in glassfish v2.1!